# Writing HTML Extensions in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Where should I write custom HTML Extension methods when the HTMLHelper Class is in the metadata(Assembly System.Web.Mvc.dll)?

Should I be updating the HTMLHelper in DLL?

Comment: Create your own namespace (say `namespace YourProject.Html`) that contains your helpers and add a reference to it in the `Web.Config` file. And if the helpers could be used across multiple projects, compile as a separate dll and reference it into your project.

Comment: What exactly you are looking for - just write your extension methods wherever you would normally write extension... Not sure what so special about taking `HtmlHelper` as first (`(this HtmlHelper html,...`) parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, just declare your methods like every other extension method. And include the namespace of your extensions class in your `Web.config` file. Then you will be able to call your methods just like you call any other `HtmlHelper` extension method.